# How i can post nested array object data to complex ICollection type property of Asp.Net Api controller as a model object by using template driven form

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-apicontroller, angular14

When i trying to post data from angular form to api controller as a model in case of simple properties like `public string Name { get; set; }` i can post data but in case of complex properties like`public virtual ICollection<AdvertisementFeature> Features { get; set; }` i am facing that error:
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI7po.png)

How i can solve that error please help me.Do i need to make changes in my features form control for handling array type data for receiving this kind of object `{id:0, name:'fgh'}`? When i directly insert that object into features property like that its transfer that data successfully.

```
addClick(){
    this.adv= {
      id: 0,
      name: 'abc',
      price: '2000',
      description: 'cde',
      features: [{id:0, name:'fgh'}]
    }
    this.ActivatePostAdvComp = true;
  }
```

**Api Model**

```
public Advertisement()
        {
            Features = new List<AdvertisementFeature>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
        public string Price { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(MAX)")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual ICollection<AdvertisementFeature> Features { get; set; }
```

**Api feature class**

```
 public class AdvertisementFeature 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
     }
```

**Angular side code:**
**Model classes:**

```
import { Feature } from "./feature.model";
export interface Advertisement{
    id: number,
    name: string,
    price: string,
    description: string,
    features: Feature[]
}
```

**Feature**

```
export interface Feature{
    id : number,
    name : string
}
```

**Component.ts class **

```
export class PostAdvComponent implements OnInit {

  
  @Input() adv: Advertisement;

  
constructor(private advertisementService: AdvertisementsService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }
  
  addAdvertisement() {
    
    console.log(this.adv);
    this.advertisementService.postAdvertisement(this.adv)
      .subscribe(add => {
        console.log(add);
      });
  }
}
```

**Html Template**

```
<form #advForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addAdvertisement()">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" href="#general" data-toggle="tab">General</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#features" data-toggle="tab">Features</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#description" data-toggle="tab">Description</a> </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content mt-4">
        <div id="general" class="tab-pane active mytab-pane">

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-prepend">
                        <label class="input-group-text"><strong>Name</strong></label>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name" [(ngModel)]="adv.name" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-prepend">
                        <label class="input-group-text"><strong>Price</strong></label>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Price" name="price"
                        [(ngModel)]="adv.price" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="features" class="tab-pane mytab-pane">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group" >
                        <span class="input-group-prepend">
                            <label class="input-group-text"><strong>Features</strong></label>
                        </span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Features" name="features"
                            [(ngModel)]="adv.features"/> 
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div id="description" class="tab-pane mytab-pane">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="12" name="description" [(ngModel)]="adv.description"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            Post Advertisement
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**service class**

```
export class AdvertisementsService {

  baseApiUrl: string = 'https://localhost:7074';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
   }
  postAdvertisement(adv: Advertisement): Observable<Advertisement> {

    return this.http.post<Advertisement>(this.baseApiUrl + '/api/advertisements',adv);
  }
```

I want to post angular side form data to Asp.Net Api controller

Comment: It should not be collection of string in the angular (`features: string[]`), it should be collection of some type

Comment: Ok you mean i need to write it like that features: any[]?

Comment: For example, depends on what exactly stored there.

Comment: I am actually storing string type data like "Stainless","Back Camera" etc

Comment: Do they have common base type?

Comment: Dear friend above you can see that i am storing features name property as a string

Comment: Then you should change your C# model to be collection of strings too. The easiest way is too match the sending and receiving sides in structure. Also I highly recommend against using the entity types as models to receive the data in the controllers to prevent overposting attacks (unless this is some test/pet/POC project).

Comment: Ok guru if i don't wanna to change above collection type then what type i should need to take in angular for features property?

Comment: "what type i should need to take in angular for features property?" a type that looks like your data model on the server side. You cannot write a string `"test"` to a data structure `{ id: 1, name: "test" }`.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen Now i declare Feature type model in angular Advertisement model class,that feature class with same data i also have in api as above i'm showing Api feature class and now i write it as feature : Features[]; in angular side advertisement model, but i am still getting same error, what i have to do now?

Comment: This line looks wrong: `fd.append('features', JSON.stringfy(this.newObj.features));` what you want: Send list of objects. What you do: Send list of strings where each string contains the json representation of an object. Solution: Remove `JSON.stringify`. Btw. you code will not send any requests because it fails before due to the typo in `stringfy()` (note the missing 'i').

Comment: Oh sorry its mistakenly i write wrong spell here in code editor its written right.

Comment: I am new in angular so you can guide me i will be thankful for that

Comment: I remove JSON.stringify() and i write it like that 'data.append('features', this.newObj.features);' its giving that error "Argument of type 'Feature[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'"

Comment: @ChristophLütjen i am waiting of your reply

Comment: ah, I see - this doesn't work with form data. Just post JSON.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen JSON.What?

Comment: The standard way to transfer structured data (objects) from an angular application to the backend is to serialize the data as JSON and the e.g. send it as a POST request. You may want to read the docs here: https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request

Comment: @ChristophLütjen How i can convert it into JSON object..In JSON i have 2 methods parse() and stringify().So kindly tell me how i can convert it into JSON object as you are saying without using these methods

Comment: Please use the search engine of your choice and search for something like "angular post Json", there are lots of tutorials available, feel free to read. Btw. as you can read in the angular documentation, the angular http client will automatically convert js objects to json and you can see how it's done in the examples.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen I have tried many different ways i am also using HttpClient service for transferring data but its giving error..Btw Thanks a lot for trying to help me